# How can I mock a class instance?

Tags: python, class, mocking

I have been mocking class functions successfully before.

But I can't seem to mock a class instance.

here is the code that I have:

```
# The below code is in the file ``exchanges.exchange``


class Meta:

    required_fields = ['security_file', 'data_file_group', 'mic']

    def __init__(self, exchange):
        self.exchange = exchange
        self.metadata = {}  # The mapping of security codes to the meta data dicts
        self.db_write = exchange.db_write`
```

And I want to mock `self.metadata`.

In my test package I do:

```
   @mock.patch('exchanges.exchange.Meta.metadata', return_value =
        {('10080', '20230104'): {'price_type': 'U', 'isin': 
          'data_file_group': 'itchebbo', 'security_file': '10080_20230104.h5'}})
   def test_check_valid_currency_no_ccy_no_Bloomberg():
       whatever...
```

When I run the test above, I get:

`AttributeError: <class 'exchanges.exchange.Meta'> does not have the attribute 'metadata'`

This leads me to believe that doing `@mock.patch` is used to mock out functions and classes, and NOT class instances? Or have I missed something basic?

I am expecting for `Meta.metadata` to be mocked out.

Comment: You don't need to use `patch` at all.  Just create an instance and assign a new value to its `metadata` attribute.

Comment: Awesome, yupp that worked. Thanks a lot Sam.

Comment: Note that you *can* use `patch.object` to patch an object as opposed to a namespace: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object but in the vast majority of cases it's not necessary.